# bad quality output when using ffmpeg and drawtext filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I have vps server and i setup ffmpeg successfully. I downloaded 720p hd video. I need only add text on video. And i added successfuly but video quality is very low after adding. I use this command

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/a.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -strict -2 c.mp4
```

I dont know -strict -2 command. i try and ffmpeg error say add -strict -2 then i add. Now i need only add text, not change video quality.

Comment: Complete ffmpeg console output is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified any bitrate. So it is going to go for default bitrate of 200kbps which will give you bad output if your size is 720p like you claim. Please specify the bitrate to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0):

Define Bitrate..

For example

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontsize=27:text=\'hellow\':x=(10):y=(main_h-30):fontcolor=white" -b:v 3M output.mp4
```